# Handling multiple user accounts in mobile applications

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile

I am trying to figure out how to handle multiple users of a mobile app in the backend.

Specifically the following use case:
1. User registers with facebook
2. User logs on with facebook. User logsout.
3. User logs on with e-mail

What is unclear to me is how the user will get filtered data, for both login situations.

The background is that I am using Azure B2C for the Sign Up / Sign in process.
Then I am using Microsoft Mobile Service Client with the access token returned from B2C.

This in return gives me a Sesssion Token.

The problem here is that all requests to the backend are made with this token and the User Id is the SID.

Now this SID changes for Facebook or Google or e-mail authentication.
If I use the SID to filter data in the backend (Claims Principal Name Identifier) then I will not get the same data.

Is there another method to filter out user data?

Comment: Not understanding why need to filter out user data.Different account has different user data, why need to filter out.

Comment: Imagine a to do list. Each user has its own items which he added. When the item list is updated he should get only his items.

Comment: Maybe this will add more info. This is the code in the backend when I read all the to do items from the database:

'code'
        public void ValidateOwner(string id)
        {
            var result = Lookup(id).Queryable.PerUserFilter(UserId).FirstOrDefault<TodoItem>();
            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
        }

        // GET tables/TodoItem
        public IQueryable<TodoItem> GetAllTodoItems()
        {
            return Query().PerUserFilter(UserId);
        }

Comment: if the same person logs in with a different set of credentials, then most applications would NOT consider them to be the same user

Comment: Bu then for example, how does an application like MyFitnessPal offer to you as a user the same data.

I logged-on with Facebook and then with my E-mail account, and I see what I logged in both situations.